# Regular Expression to remove numbers ending with "," or "."

Tags: regex

I am trying to generate regular expression in java to parse financial entities from strings. I need to write a regex in such a way that numbers ending with "." or "," should be removed, like

> 15,
>   15.

where as if values like

> 15,303(currency )
>   15.55(rate)

should be taken.

Comment: ReGex is not needed here. Try searching for substring.

Comment: Your "question" is not clear. Do you want to remove the numbers ending with `,.` from a string or do you want to extract numbers with a fraction from the string? And What have you tried? Provide an example string and the code where you are failing.

Comment: I would definitelly use regex here.. It's about separator followed by a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^\d+[,.]$/
```

You can play with it [here](http://rubular.com/r/nsXMDzQtAG).

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like:

```
(\d+)[\.,][^\d]
```

Where the group captures digits followed by `.` or `,` and not continuing with other digit.

Answer (score 0):

`\d+(\.|,)\d+` for your should be taken values

Answer (score 0):

To remove such numbers (example in Python, but should work in nearly any regex flavor):

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\d+[.,](?!\d)")
>>> regex.sub("", "15 15,0 15, 15. 15.0 15")
'15 15,0   15.0 15'
```

To find only "correct" numbers:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?![\d.,])\b")
>>> regex.findall("15 15,0 15, 15. 15.0 15")
['15', '15,0', '15.0', '15']
```